# SELECT Value from array

Tags: sql-server

There is an array `@array = select username from usertable`
and the **parameter** is passed to the other query

```
SELECT
*
FROM transactiontable TT
WHERE TT.name in (SELECT value FROM string_split(@array, ','))
```

What is the benifit of doing this?

Can't I just do `SELECT * from transcationtbale TT WHERE TT.name in @array`?

Also, what is `SELECT value FROM expression`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'username' field in 'usertable' is a string like 'user1, user2, user3'. Is it right?

If it is not, then use such query:

```
 SELECT * from transcationtbale TT WHERE TT.name in (select username from usertable)
```

Answer (score 1):

`STRING_SPLIT` is used to separate string by specified separator. Please, [read this description at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
Let me show an example:

```
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('Adam,Joseph,Jon',',')
```

But if you select from table, then use just:

```
SELECT UserName FROM UserTable
```

There is no benefit between them, it cannot be comparable, it is like compare apples and oranges.

Comment: @arrray is passing from SQL Report Server. What kind of format we will get from select username from usertable? Isn't that an array as well?

Comment: @NewPy coluld you show the sample date of `@array`?